# Xcode MFMessageComposeViewController status bar & text field

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, uitextfield

I created in my Xcode project an form that has 2 text fields in which does the user insert his current address and destination . And when I click on the Send return key in the second text field , the message compose controller appears well .

But, the problem is that the body of the message isn't "dragging" the value from text field and the message . So I want the value from my text fields have in the message body . 
Where is the problem ?

```
-(IBAction)btnSendSms:(id)sender {


    [sender resignFirstResponder];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication ] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {

        controller.body = @"My body text %@: " , textField1.text , textField2.text;

        controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"011888",nil];
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        controller.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should correct the body String:

```
controller.body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My body text %@: %@", textField1.text, textField2.text ];
```